# Need help solving a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am preparing for finals and there is one exercise in my book that i don`t know how to solve.
$$\frac{\sin a}{\sin \frac{a}{b}}=b$$

I just need to solve this for b. I tried wolfram alpha but it does not seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a usual trigonometric equation...and neither an easy one. Are you sure that's the expression? Aren't there any conditions on the angles $\;a,b\;$ ?

Comment: No, exercise asks to solve this for b and does not say anything about a and b.

Comment: @Radon Is this a high school math problem? If so, are you sure you copied it down correctly? I don't know if there's some kind of trick to this problem, but this seems way too hard for high school.

Comment: what is the original problem?

Comment: That is a truly beautiful graph. Thank you.

Comment: How did you get the graph? I tried several plotting tools but neither seems to work for this equation.

Comment: This is the original problem - solving the equation for b. And its not a high school math problem.

Comment: What graph are you people talking about?!

Comment: I just realized that $b=1$ works.

Comment: @NobleMushtak So does $\;b=-1\;$, and in both cases $\;a\neq k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ , but I doubt that's the way meant...

Comment: $$\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin a}{\sin a/b}=\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin a}{a}\frac{\sin a/b}{a/b}b=b$$
For $a=0$ any $b\ne0$ is a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ your equation can be written as:
$$ f(a) = f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) $$
so $b=\pm 1$ is always a solution ($f$ is an even function), and there may be other solutions (a finite amount, if $a\not\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$) if $a$ is sufficiently far from the origin, by just considering the behaviour of the graph of $f(x)$. For instance, if $a=3$ there are $14$ solutions:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

In general, the number of solutions is bounded by the ratio between a fixed constant and the distance of $a$ from $\pi\mathbb{Z}$, since $f(x)$ is a Lipschitz-continuous function with bounded derivative.

Comment: I need a solution for b. b = f(a) = ... . Thats what solution for b is. letter b is on the right side of equation and the everything else is on the left side of equation. I think i would manage to get b values for a given a, but i need a generic solution.

Comment: @Radon: $b=\pm 1$ is a generic solution and we cannot provide much more: you cannot ask for a function that takes $14$ different values at $a=3$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, but for example polynomial equation, you can get there it is equal y and get all those x values. I just wondering is there a way to get all b values with a given a. I just want to know if there is a way to get all points there f(a) = f(a/b) with a given a. For example if a=3 is there a way to get all those 14 values?

Comment: @Radon: $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is *way* different from a polynomial. We cannot even give an explicit form to the solutions of $\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{1}{7}$, for instance. The associated equation is essentially Kepler's equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation).

Comment: Physicists would be glad to have a closed form solution of Kepler's equation, but sadly, there isn't. However, Kepler's equation can be efficiently solved numerically through Newton's method.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Could you explane me what do you mean by saying that the number of solutions is bounded by the ratio between fixed constant and the distance of a from piZ ?

Comment: @Radon: I mean what I mean. Do you know how the distance of a point from a set is defined? $$ d(a,E) = \min_{e\in E}\|a-e\|.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio what is that fixed constant? And no, i do not know how that distance is defined.

Comment: @Radon: I do not think the exact value of the absolute constant is really relevant, but I might compute it if you like. Anyway, $d(a,E)$ is defined above.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am asking because i have a similar problem like in my orginal post, but this time i just need to get the number of solution for a given a.

Answer (score 1):

On the (admittedly debatable) assumption that the question means

> Find all real $b$ such that  $\frac{\sin a}{\sin \frac{a}{b}} = b$ for all real $a \neq 0$,

there are precisely two solutions: $b = \pm1$.

First, rewrite the condition
$$
\sin a = b\sin \tfrac{a}{b}\quad\text{for all real $a \neq 0$,}
$$
and note that $b \neq 0$ (since the left side is not identically zero). The left side is periodic in $a$ with smallest positive period $2\pi$; the right side is periodic in $a$ with smallest positive period $2\pi|b|$. It follows that $|b| = 1$.